# SharePoint 2013 and Office Web Apps - Unable to view documents

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, office-web-apps, ssl

We have a Web Applications Companion (WAC) server connected to our SharePoint 2013 web application (*upgraded to claims based authentication*). It appears to us that the WAC server does not trust the SSL certificate on the SharePoint web application. All certificates in question are generated by our domain Certificate Authority (CA).

The error recieved on SharePoint is as follows:

> Microsoft Word Web App
>
> Sorry, there was a problem and we can't open this document. If this happens again, try opening the document in Microsoft Word.

The errors received on the WAC server are as follows:

> HttpRequestAsync WOPICheckFile WACSERVER  no response [WebExceptionStatus:TrustFailure, url:https://...
>    WOPICheckFile WACSERVER HttpRequestAsyncException url:https://... Microsoft.Office.Web.Apps.Common.HttpRequestAsyncException: No Response in WebException ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel. ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure
>    WOPI CheckFile: Catch-All Failure [exception:Microsoft.Office.Web.Common.EnvironmentAdapters.UnexpectedErrorException: HttpRequest failed ---> Microsoft.Office.Web.Apps.Common.HttpRequestAsyncException: No Response in WebException ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel. ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
>    FileUnknownException while loading the app.

Everything was setup while strictly adhering to the following:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219455.aspx

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431687.aspx

The commands ran on the WAC Server:

```
New-OfficeWebAppsFarm -InternalUrl "https://wacserver" -ExternalUrl "https://wacserver.domain-dev.com" –CertificateName "wacserver.domain-dev.com" -EditingEnabled -Verbose  -ClipartEnabled -TranslationEnable
```

The commands ran on the SharePoint 2013 server:

```
 New-SPWOPIBinding -ServerName wacserver.domain-dev.com
 Get-SPWOPIZone
 Set-SPWOPIZone –zone "external-https"
```

The certificate on the SharePoint web application is named **intranet-dev.domain-dev.com**

The certificate on the WAC server is named **wacserver.domain-dev.com**

If necessary I can post the full URL log entry surrounding this error.

Comment: Have you checked that the setting is set to external https using Get-SPWOPIZone?

Comment: As per my comments above we already ran the Get-SPWOPIZone command. Due to a lack of response here (and in various other locations) we have resorted to bringing in some consultants to help us get this corrected. Real shame since this seems like a pretty normal scenario.

Comment: if you want to highlight a question, you could always start a [bounty](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/bounty). And please don't forget that this Q&A is built on individuals working for free...

Comment: Perhaps, once your consultants have solved the problem, you could share the solution here to help other users.

Comment: @BennySkogberg I am fully aware of how StackExchange functions. Thank you for your input.

Comment: @SpDoctor Actually we figured the issue out this morning and I was about to post the solution.

Comment: Did you install OWA on anything other than the C drive?
If you did, uninstall it, reinstall it to the c drive and rebind.

Comment: Not exactly answering your question, but quite helpful for a lot of similar problems: [Office Web Apps Server 2013 - machines are always reported as Unhealthy](http://www.wictorwilen.se/office-web-apps-server-2013---machines-are-always-reported-as-unhealthy)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The AutoSPInstaller (http://autospinstaller.codeplex.com/) was actually creating self-signed certificates on the server that the WAC did not trust. So we had to manually create the certs and a CA so that the trust would work properly. This corrected our issue.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was difficult to resolve, but I found that exporting the self-signed certificate from the SharePoint environment and importing it with the key in all WAC servers resolved the issue.

We have test VM's with self-signed certificates automatically generated by running a modified AutoSPInstaller.

Error found in WAC ULS:

> exception:System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel. ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

URL that lead to solution: http://blog.sharepointsite.co.uk/2014/01/office-web-app-ran-into-problem-opening.html